Prove the limit of $f_n$ is measurable by a small modification
The following lemma seems very important when proving theorems in measure theory (My professor emphasized it a lot). I have two questions about it.

What does it try to tell us? Why is it useful and important?
I do not understand the proof and I highlighted parts that confuse me.

Lemma: Let $\left(f_n\right)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ be a sequence of measurable functions from $E$ into $\mathbb{R}$. The set $A$ of all $x \in E$ such that $f_n(x)$ converges in $\mathbb{R}$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$ is measurable. Furthermore, the function $h: E \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$ defined by
$$
h(x):= \begin{cases}\lim _{n \rightarrow \infty} f_n(x) & \text { if } x \in A, \\ 0 & \text { if } x \notin A,\end{cases}
$$
is measurable.
Proof For the first assertion, let $G$ be the measurable function from $E$ into $\overline{\mathbb{R}}^2$ defined by $G(x):=\left(\lim \inf f_n(x), \lim \sup f_n(x)\right)$ ($G$ is measurable with respect to $\mathcal{B}(\overline{\mathbb{R}}) \otimes \mathcal{B}(\overline{\mathbb{R}})$, then why $\mathcal{B}(\overline{\mathbb{R}}^2)$, and set $\Delta=\{(x, x): x \in \mathbb{R}\}$. Then
$$
A=\left\{x \in E:-\infty<\liminf f_n(x)=\lim \sup f_n(x)<\infty\right\}=G^{-1}(\Delta)
$$
The measurability of $A$ follows since $\Delta$ is a measurable subset of $\overline{\mathbb{R}}^2$ (note that $\{(x, x): x \in {\mathbb{R}}\}$ is measurable as a closed subset of $\left.\overline{\mathbb{R}}^2\right)$. (Why? I only know the diagonal is closed in ${\mathbb{R}}^2$)
Then let $F \in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$ with $0 \notin F$. We observe that
$$
h^{-1}(F)=A \cap\left\{x \in E: \lim \sup f_n(x) \in F\right\}
$$
and use the previous proposition to get that $h^{-1}(F)$ is measurable. If $0 \in F$ we just write $h^{-1}(F)^c=h^{-1}\left(F^c\right)$.
